# Bash script echos but won't execute

Tags: bash

I'm creating a simple bash script to remove all Bluetooth devices from my system.  What it does is use `bt-device -l` to list the bluetooth devices, then grabs the MAC address in between the parens, then calls `bt-device -r <MACAddress>` to remove the device.  I'm not that great at bash scripts but when I replace the bt-device call with echo, I get the correct output.  When I put the command back in it says the device wasn't found.  If I manually make the call it works (outputs "Done").

Sample output of the `bt-device -l` command:

```
Added Devices:
Samico BP (12:34:56:78:9a:bc)
SensorTag 2.0 (12:34:56:78:9a:bd)
```

And the script I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bt-device -l | sed 1d |
while read x; do
    bt-device -r $x | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1
done
```

When I run it, it runs the `bt-device -r` command but the output is `Error: Device not found` as if I'd typed the MAC address wrong. If I replace the `bt-device` call in the script with `echo`, I get the list of MAC addresses as expected.

**Updated script working**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bt-device -l | sed 1d |
while read x; do
    bt-device -r $(echo $x | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1)
done
```

Comment: I should see ```Done``` for each bluetooth device it finds in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're running `cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1` on the *output* of `bt-device -r`, instead of on its *argument*.

Instead, you should write something like this:

```
bt-device -l | sed 1d | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1 |
while read x; do
     bt-device -r $x
done
```

Comment: This is the real answer, though using echo I was able to rectify it as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to process `$x` prior to using it:

```
bt-device -l | sed 1d |
while read x; do
    dev=$( echo "$x" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1 )
    bt-device -r "$dev"
done
```

Comment: While it turns out your reasoning is a little off, your answer helped me to realize I just needed to echo the cut outputs to get the proper string.  See updated question.  Thanks!

Comment: Why is it off? ) In your original code you basically do this: ```bt-device -r (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) | cut ...``` while the proper way is first cut the brackets, then use the result.

Comment: Actually I guess the reasoning was not off.  Just creating the extra variable was not necessary.

Comment: So you wanna optimize, huh? ```bt-device -l | sed '1d;s#.*(\([^)]\+\))#\1#' | while read x; do bt-device -r $x; done```   =p

Comment: I know you're joking and that does work, but then I don't get the ```Done``` output for each device :)